# XSL XPatch for-each filtering for an attribute that doesnt exist

Tags: xml, xslt

XML ex.

```
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#OGRGeoJSON">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">33503</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Objecttype">VELOSTATION</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Type_velo">ENKELZIJDIG</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ligging">PLEIN</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Straatnaam">Koningin Astridplein (2018)</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="District">ANTWERPEN</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Postcode">2018</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Objectcode">VE_0000171</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Gebruik">IN_GEBRUIK</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Aantal_plaatsen">12</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>4.420745567350077,51.217857547604396</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#OGRGeoJSON">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">33504</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Objecttype">VELOSTATION</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Type_velo">DUBBELZIJDIG</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ligging">VOETPAD</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Straatnaam">Paardenmarkt (2000)</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Huisnummer">43</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="District">ANTWERPEN</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Postcode">2000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Objectcode">VE_0000165</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Gebruik">GEPLAND</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Aantal_plaatsen">36</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>4.409111155407346,51.22513798273102</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#OGRGeoJSON">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">33505</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Objecttype">VELOSTATION</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Type_velo">ENKELZIJDIG</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ligging">PLEIN</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Straatnaam">Koningin Astridplein (2018)</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="District">ANTWERPEN</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Postcode">2018</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Objectcode">VE_0000172</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Aantal_plaatsen">12</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>4.420622573479942,51.217862009361745</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
```

XSL for-each ex.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Placemark/ExtendedData/SchemaData[SimpleData[@name = 'Gebruik'] != 'GEPLAND']">
<xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
```

So I need to create a filtering statement that gets everything except where "gebruik" = GEPLAND, and where its not present. I need to filter them out to get a correct ID for the database since im making an insert statement from this data.

I've tried a bunch of things but can't seem to get this working.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want. And your input is not well-formed XML (no single root element). Please edit you question and (1) fix your input and (2) show the exact output you expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the path `/Placemark/ExtendedData/SchemaData[SimpleData[@name = 'Gebruik'] = 'IN_GEBRUIK' or not(SimpleData[@name = 'Gebruik'])]` implements your verbal description "filtering statement that gets both records where name="Gebruik = IN_GEBRUIK, and where its not present".

Comment: I tried to use the not statement but it didn't seem to work when I tried it but maybe there was something else that was causing problems, I'll try this when I get the chance

Answer (score 0):

***--- edited ---***

This predicate:

```
[not(SimpleData[@name='Gebruik'] = 'GEPLAND')]
```

will exclude records where `SimpleData[@name='Gebruik']` has the value of  "GEPLAND".

---

This predicate:

```
[SimpleData[@name='Gebruik'] != 'GEPLAND']
```

will exclude records where `SimpleData[@name='Gebruik']` has the value of  "GEPLAND" **or** `SimpleData[@name='Gebruik']` does not exist at all.

Comment: Sorry I should have formulated it differently since I need everything except where Gebruik = GEPLAND Ive changed it in my question since there are some other values it can be that I didnt include

Comment: I am afraid you are still being too vague. See if my edited answer solves your problem.